# When I delete a row in datatable does not disappear - primefaces - Java?

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a table with the options of delete and edit. When I clicked the delete button, the data does not not disappear. Then when I click refresh on my browser, and the information is deleted.

What is wrong?

```
<p:dataTable id="tabla2" value="#{b_rep.tabla}" var="o"  widgetVar="56" style="width: 600px;" editable="true">
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{b_rep.onEdit}" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{b_rep.onCancel}" />    

    <f:facet name="header">Información subida</f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Punto de venta" filterBy="#{o.nombre}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:facet name="header">  
             <h:outputText value="Nombre" />  
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{o.nombre}" />                         
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Fecha" filterBy="#{o.fecha}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Fecha"/>  
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{o.fecha}">  
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
        </h:outputText>    
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Opc" style="width:60px">  
        <p:rowEditor></p:rowEditor>
    </p:column> 

</p:dataTable>
```

This is the method that deletes information from the table:

```
public void onCancel(RowEditEvent event) {  
    try {
       rep_struct change = (rep_struct) event.getObject();

       BD bd = new BD();
       Connection con = bd.Conectar(url);

       String sql = "DELETE FROM ventas";
       sql += " WHERE codpv=?";
       sql += " AND fecha=?";


       PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);         
       ps.setString(1, change.getPdv());
       ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(change.getFecha().getTime()));

       ps.executeUpdate();
       ps.close();

       //cargar_tabla();
       tabla.remove((rep_struct) event.getObject());

       FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Item Borrado");
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(rep_bean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Deleting a row on rowEditCancel? I've never seen that... Or kan you only edit a row when you ADD one?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{b_rep.onEdit}" update="tabla2"/>  
  <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{b_rep.onCancel}" update="tabla2"/>
```

you need to update the datatable